# npm install on-board dont work,i tried anything

Tags: npm, npm-install

I  want install bnc-onboard but it dont work nothing is help i try npm install bnc-onboard

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7N2Z.png)

Comment: Did you check the log file it references?

Comment: Please upload the complete log file so everyone has more information to pin point where the problem is.

Comment: You want debug logs file?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the package and the git rep related to the package.
Although you can try to install the version with more downloads that would be 1.37.0 (if you don't need the latest version).
You can do it simply by:

```
npm i bnc-onboard@1.37.0
```

comment if the version is not installing or having other problems.

Comment: Again same problem nothing worked

Comment: Can you please check if the NPM is the latest version? you can do it by: npm install -g npm. It would update the npm and then you can try to install bnc again